# How do I add each new element in table to top of table when each element is dynamically created from server using angularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In the following code, I am creating a table that uses AngularJS to grab information from a server and adds each item to a table using 'ng-repeat'.

```
<table class=" table table-striped" id="eventTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Index</th>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Source</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="event in eventslist">
        <tr>
            <td>{{event.idx}}</td>
            <td class="text-left" nowrap>
                {{event.srvTime | date :'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'}}
            </td>
            <td class="text-left">
                <a data-ui-sref="events.details({edIdx: event.idx})">{{event.desc}}</a>
            </td>
            <td class="text-left" nowrap>
                {{event.s0.id}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have polling set up on the web page from the javascript controller(see below) so it stays near 'real-time'. I need each new item coming in to be added to the top of the table, how do I do this, should it be in the controller or can I do it straight from the HTML file? Thanks!

```
$scope.latestEventIndex = 0;
        var poll;

        eventsFactory.getEvents()
        .success(function (result) {
            angular.forEach(result.v, function (d) {
                $scope.eventslist.push(d);
                if (d.idx > $scope.latestEventIndex) {
                    $scope.latestEventIndex = d.idx;
                }
            });
        $rootScope.eventslist = $scope.eventslist;
        })
            .error(function (error) {
                $scope.status = 'Unable to get events: ' +error.message;
                console.log($scope.status);
        });

        poll = $interval(function() {
            eventsFactory.getLatestEvents($scope.latestEventIndex)
            .success(function (result) {
                angular.forEach(result.v, function (d) {
                    $scope.eventslist.push(d);
                    if (d.idx > $scope.latestEventIndex) {
                        $scope.latestEventIndex = d.idx;  
                    }
                });
                $rootScope.eventslist = $scope.eventslist;
            })
            .error(function (error) {
                $scope.status = 'Unable to get events: ' + error.message;
                console.log($scope.status);
            });
        }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your array does not appear to be sorted, you can simply insert the new items into the $scope.eventlists array using `Array.splice`.  [Here's a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sHwBba7dDc6NBCMPaW7P?p=preview):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">
  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="mycon">
    <h1>{{test}}</h1>
    <div>
      <div ng-repeat="item in list">{{item}}</div>
    </div>
    <input ng-model="newItem" />
    <button ng-click="addItemAtTopOfList()">Add</button>
    <script>
      var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
      app.controller('mycon', function($scope){
        $scope.list = [];
        $scope.addItemAtTopOfList = function(){
          $scope.list.splice(0, 0, $scope.newItem);
          $scope.newItem = "";
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Let me know if that doesn't answers your question sufficiently.

Comment: It's not shown here but the array is sorted by another services javascript file. The information it gets from the server is already sorted when it comes in. When you initially visit the webpage everything is sorted perfectly, the problem is that when ever the server changes I am sending new events to the webpage and right now it adds those events to the bottom, new information coming in should be added to the top to remain in order. Does this make sense? @threed

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense, but ng-repeat should keep the sorted order even when adding new items.  What are you sorting on?  And are you sure your new items have the appropriate sort value?

Comment: Each item coming from the server is based on an ID number. The way I'm getting the information is by a URI that basically says, "Give me these events with these filters" and I can specify whether they come back in reverse order or forward order and then store them in my array. The ng-repeat does keep it in order in each chunk of data but any neew data coming in gets sorted and then appended to the end. @threed

Comment: Could you provide some example json of the array you are trying to add and the array already in the repeater?

Comment: I was able to fix the issue, it was a very dumb mistake when adding to my array and once I fixed that your answer worked. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked out.  It might be worth noting your mistake here in case anyone runs into the same issue and finds this post.